# Connecting to Flask SocketIO implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, socket.io

I'm having some issues trying to connect to a Flask SocketIO implementation. I followed the examples and set up a server with the following code:

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send

application = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(application)

@socketio.on('message')
def doStuff(msg):
    print(msg)

if __name__=="__main__":
  socketio.run(application, port=8080)
```

and a client in Python:

```
import websocket
from websocket import create_connection

ws = create_connection("ws://SERVER_IP:8080/")
print(ws)

print("Sending 'Hello, World'...")
ws.send("Hello, World")
print("Sent")

print("Receiving...")
result =  ws.recv()
print("Received '%s'" % result)
ws.close()
```

Nonetheless when I try to connect, I get **WebSocketBadStatusException: Handshake status 200 OK**. All the examples I've seen of connection to SocketIO involve having a static page with javascript but I want to use this as a Desktop application or use it with Kotlin.

What am I missing?

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Just that I get WebSocketBadStatusException, and can't get response from the server. But just got information by lain iwakura that the protocols aren't compatible.

Comment: your problem has nothing to do with PyQt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flask-SocketIO is not a WebSocket server, it is a Socket.IO server. The client that you need to use needs to understand the Socket.IO protocol, a WebSocket client alone is not enough. [reference](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/270#issuecomment-226016010)

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48160130/using-flask-socketio-and-the-socketio-client).

Comment: Oh I see, was afraid that would be the case. Oh well, thanks a lot for your answer and time! Guess I'll switch to Websockets.